# ClassCastException in JPA query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, migration

I am trying to migrate from spring-boot 2.6.6 to spring-boot 3.0.2. Although, i get some really weird error in the custom queries which used to work in the previous version.

For example, in the following query:

```
entityManager.createQuery(
            "SELECT distinct me FROM myEntity me " +
                    "WHERE me.deleted = false " +
                    "AND me.parent is null AND me.id IN (:ids) " +
                    "AND ((:type) is null OR me.type = :type) " +
                    "AND ((lower(me.label) LIKE lower(:name)) OR (lower(me.description) LIKE lower(:name))) " +
                    "AND ((:created) is null OR me.createdBy IN (:created)) " +
                    "AND ((:models) is null OR me.model IN (:models))")
            .setParameter("name", "%" + name + "%").setParameter("ids", ids)
            .setParameter("created", creators).setParameter("type", type)
            .setParameter("models", models)
            .getResultList()
```

This query is now throwing `ClassCastException@786 "java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.util.ArrayList and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')"`

The variables are:

- name: String
- ids: List of Long
- created: List of String
- type: List of Enum
- models: List of String

In the example i am trying to run name = "", ids contains 1 number which exists in the database, creators and type are null and models contains 1 string.

This issue is getting more weird as if i just run the following code then it works as expected:

```
    entityManager.createQuery(
            "SELECT distinct me FROM myEntity me " +
                    "WHERE me.deleted = false " +
                    "AND me.parent is null AND me.id IN (:ids) " +
                    "AND ((:type) is null OR me.type = :type) " +
                    "AND lower(me.description) LIKE lower(:name) " +
                    "AND ((:created) is null OR me.createdBy IN (:created)) " +
                    "AND ((:models) is null OR me.model IN (:models))")
            .setParameter("name", "%" + name + "%").setParameter("ids", ids)
            .setParameter("created", creators).setParameter("type", type)
            .setParameter("models", models)
            .getResultList()
```

Additionally, if i put two elements in models list then in the second case i get an `index out of bounds error. Index: 0`

Do you have any idea or proposal? I face that issue in multiple cases for String and Enum type lists.

Thank you a lot for your time!

Answer (score 2):

SpringBoot 3+ uses Hibernate 6+. And Hibernate has opted to optimize everything and stepped away from being fully backwards compatible. Meaning that they've become stricter.

If you have a class, with for example:

```
 @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
 @Column(name = "myDBcolumn")
 private MyEnum myEnum;
```

Then, as of old, Hibernate will use your getters and setters when resolving a HQL/JPQL query. And since your variable has been defined as an Enum, which (in this example) writes the Enum.name(), a String-value, to your database column. It no longers automatically infers Strings to Enums. Meaning that the following no longer works:

```
@Query("SELECT mc FROM MyClass mc " +
       "WHERE mc.myEnum IN (:myEnumList)")
List<MyClass> findByMatchingEnum(@Param("myEnumList") List<String> values);
```

As you noted, allthough in your case you're comparing ArrayList to String (might refer to another issue), **the Types must match!** So in my example above, I'd have to pass
`List<MyEnum> values` as parameter to my query in order for it to work again after migrating to Hibernate 6+.

Another way to go about it, would be to write your own AttributeConverter according to the docs, but in my case, it still throws a ClassCastException with select-queries.

There is a very comprehensive [migration guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/migration-guide/migration-guide.html) and if you don't use to much fluff, then this [lightweight guide](https://thorben-janssen.com/migrating-to-hibernate-6/) is perhaps useful.
And if you have a very nice little plugin called JPA-buddy, then maybe you'd be interested in the [new features and highlights](https://jpa-buddy.com/blog/hibernate6-whats-new-and-why-its-important/) of Hibernate 6+.

*Footnote:*
I decided to migrate legacy applications early to SpringBoot 3+. The changes Hibernate 6+ enforces, has had further implications than I'd initially assessed. Especially with the now read-by-position changes. For example, I found it easier to re-write old native SQL queries to their proper JPQL format.

Comment: Hello Paul, Thanks a lot for your reply! I had aborted the migration but soon i am gonna start it again so i will come back then in order to leave proper feedback!